# How to test this function in Python... TypeError: object not callable

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Can't test the function `slowest_call` with 3 arguments.

This is one of my learning exercises. First I defined the `time_call` function, then I'm trying to use it as an input in another function, `slowest_call`.

Maybe my inputs are not quite right (what can I put as the 4th input?!). Not sure what else to try.

```
from time import sleep
from time import time
t = time()
sleep(duration)


 """Return the amount of time the given function takes (in seconds) when called with the given argument """

def time_call(fn, arg):
    t0 = time()
    fn(arg)
    t1 = time()
    elapsed = t1 - t0
    return elapsed
time_call(sleep, 4)  # testing it, it works

 """"Return the amount of time taken by the slowest of the following function
    calls: fn(arg1), fn(arg2), fn(arg3) """

def slowest_call(fn, arg1, arg2, arg3):
return max(time_call(fn, arg1), time_call(fn, arg2), time_call(fn, arg3))
```

I'm testing it like this

```
slowest_call(time_call(sleep,5), time_call(sleep,3), time_call(sleep,2))

TypeError: slowest_call() missing 1 required positional argument: 'arg3'
```

It gives gives me the error while it should generate the longest time as an answer (5...).

Comment: Please ensure your posted code is correctly indented.
You should be passing a function and 3 arguments to slowest_call, In the same way that you provide a function to time_call.

Comment: Also worth mentioning is that the error in your topic title is not the same error that your text shows. They should match up.

Comment: didn't you make the function? how do you not know how to use it? :c

Answer (score 1):

But that isn't at all how your `slowest_call` function is expecting to be called. It wants the callable function itself, and then three arguments to use to call it. And it takes care of calling `time_call` for you. So:

```
slowest_call(sleep, 5, 3, 2)
```